wifi(wlan) not working on ubuntu 24.04?
i think the error is in the image
I recently updated to Unbuntu 24.04 LTS version. During that day everything worked fine but today I encountered a problem connecting to my wifi, It no longer works. I restarted my computer, but I can no longer connect to the internet. Any Ideas how to solve this problem?

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos then edit the question to include the wireless script results
